# Access using an SQL JOIN or similar statement as a record source for a report

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

```
SELECT * 
FROM QryMain 
WHERE [Plant Number] IN (SELECT [Plant Number] FROM [QryProceduresDone]);
```

Hi all.

Currently using the above as a report record source.

Basically I want the report to show only records from QryMain that also have corresponding records in QryProceduresDone. Both Queries have the `[Plant Number]` field.

The above statement works fine but I believe it could slow down if having to deal with many records.

I believe using a `JOIN` statement is much more efficient and have tried various attempts at using join without success.

Can anyone please help in suggesting a way to apply a join or any other alternative statement that is more efficient than what I am using?

Using Access 2010.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent code with a join would be:

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM QryMain AS m INNER JOIN QryProceduresDone AS pd
ON pd.[Plant Number] = m.[Plant Number];
```

but a join may return duplicates if the relation of the tables is not 1:1 and also I'm not sure if this would make any significant difference in performance.

What may be better is `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM QryMain AS m 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM QryProceduresDone AS pd WHERE pd.[Plant Number] = m.[Plant Number]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much forpas this has worked using EXISTS but I did it slightly different

Comment: I used SELECT * FROM QryMain WHERE EXISTS (SELECT [Plant Number] FROM QryProceduresDone WHERE QryMain.[Plant Number] = QryProceduresDone.[Plant Number]);

Comment: You could use `SELECT *...` or `SELECT 0...` or `SELECT NULL...`. It makes no difference. Also it's a good practice to use aliases instead of the table names in queries where more than 1 tables are involved. It makes the code shorter and more readable. And don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.